# Python - import two lists into a class and use operator overload to add them

Tags: python

So I'm having a difficult time trying to figure out how classes work. Basically I converted two polynomials (3x^2 + 2x + 8) & (8x^2 - 4x - 2) into lists - [3, 2, 8] & [8, -4, -2] and I want to use an operator overload to add them to gether via a class. All I need to do is import these two lists into my class and then return the sum to be used in a different part of my program [11, -2, 6]. Here's what I got so far but I'm very new to classes and don't know what I'm doing. I tried looking up how to do it but have gotten very confused in the process.

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, poly1List, poly2List):
        self.poly1List = poly1List
        self.poly2List = poly2List
    def __add__(self, poly1List, poly2List):
        return finalPolyList( self.poly1List + self.poly2List)
```

then I want to be able to do

```
finalPolyList = poly1List + poly2List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `list` as metaclass, make it easier and shorter:

```
class Polynomial(list):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Polynomial(list(map(sum,zip(self,other))))
```

Example calling:

```
poly1List=Polynomial([3, 2, 8])
poly2List=Polynomial([8, -4, -2])
finalPolyList = poly1List+poly2List
```

Or:

```
poly1List=Polynomial([3, 2, 8])
poly2List=[8, -4, -2]
finalPolyList = poly1List+poly2List
```

Both cases:

```
print(finalPolyList)
```

Is:

```
[11, -2, 6]
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a nice way to do this.

Comment: @JoshuaSmith Happy to help!!, :-), :D, , (don't need to create a class for dong all the stuff, steal it from `list` builtin, then add what you want since you're doing a list :D)

Comment: *base* class not metaclass. I don't really see the point of inheritance here. Composition seems more appropriate. Is a polynomial a list? No, not really. The list is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want a Polynomial class that overloads `+`, so it's not clear why the constructor is taking two lists unless `Polynomial` is some kind of container.

Here's a simple way to overload the `__add__` with just one class:

```
class Polynomial:
    def __init__(self, polylist):
        self.list = polylist
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Polynomial([x + y for x, y in zip(self.list, other.list)])
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}({self.list})"

p1 = Polynomial([3, 2, 8])
p2 = Polynomial([8, -4, -2])

p3 = p1 + p2 # Polynomial ([11, -2, 6])
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Pretty much yea, just had a few questions though, what is the purpose of __repr__, and is there a way I could rewrite the return for __add__ because that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: I added the __repr__ so if you just ran p1 + p2 on the command line it would print out something meaningful. You can write the add method in a lot of ways, for example you would make a for loop or use `map`. You might also add a __str__ method so it will print() nicely.